# SG electret microphone static impedance

Tags: microphone, electret, condenser-microphone

I have an SG electret microphone (see figure below) connected to my phone, and it produces pretty bad signals (keeps mostly the low frequencies while killing the high frequencies). I suspect it is the microphone (although it might be something else in the circuit). The microphone has a static resistance (without any voltage applied) not lower than 1.5KOhm (I can't measure it exactly since I can't take it out of the circuit, and there are additional things connected in parallel to it). I can't find datasheet on it, so maybe someone had a deal with them before.
When I apply voltage to it (1 Volt), the current through it is 0.2mA.

The question is: are these parameters OK for this microphone? Or it is damaged?

[image: SG electret microphone]

Comment: Electret mics usually have JFETs in them, that may want more than 1v supply.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the ECMs I've used/seen operate between 1V - 10V.

Also, the frequency response of these guys vary quite a bit. Some ECMs and/or MEMS mics are optimized for a particular bandwidth. For many telephony applications (300Hz - ~3kHz) you'll find a high frequency rolloff, which may be what you're seeing. May want to try out a couple other mics.

Answer (score 0):

1V/0.2mA sounds typical.  Low-voltage electrets are typically specced about 1.5V/0.3mA with a 3dB point about 1.1V.

Higher specced ones may start at 2V/0.5mA (and generally, 0.5mA is standard except for low-power capsules).

However, underpowering an electret capsule will affect SNR and might add non-linear distortion.  It doesn't really impact the frequency response all that much, so there really is the question what the rest of the circuitry around it is doing to the signal.

Comment: Most of the thousands of electret mics sold at Digikey are used at 5V/0.5mA and a minimum of 2V. None cut high audio frequencies.